# Error in fetching "images" and "labels" using Keras next() with tf.keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
assert batch_obj['train'].n == sample_size['train'] * len(data_types)
assert batch_obj['valid'].n == sample_size['valid'] * len(data_types)
assert batch_obj['test'].n == sample_size['test'] * len(data_types)
assert batch_obj['train'].num_classes == batch_obj['train'].num_classes \
    == batch_obj['train'].num_classes == len(data_types)
```

When I try,

```
train_images, train_labels = next(batch_obj['train'])
```

errors out with,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-674a9be77381> in <module>
----> 1 train_images, train_labels = next(batch_obj['train'])

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py in __next__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    102 
    103     def __next__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 104         return self.next(*args, **kwargs)
    105 
    106     def next(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py in next(self)
    114         # The transformation of images is not under thread lock
    115         # so it can be done in parallel
--> 116         return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
    117 
    118     def _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array)
    229                            target_size=self.target_size,
    230                            interpolation=self.interpolation)
--> 231             x = img_to_array(img, data_format=self.data_format)
    232             # Pillow images should be closed after `load_img`,
    233             # but not PIL images.

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py in img_to_array(img, data_format, dtype)
    307     # or (channel, height, width)
    308     # but original PIL image has format (width, height, channel)
--> 309     x = np.asarray(img, dtype=dtype)
    310     if len(x.shape) == 3:
    311         if data_format == 'channels_first':

/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I can't figure out what's wrong here ....
Hoping to get some help resolving this.

Best,
M

Comment: Try to downgrade PIL from 8.3 to 8.2. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68238057/typeerror-array-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given-image-class/68239032#68239032

Comment: Thank you so much, Lulian. Much appreciated! Pillow 8.2.0 did the trick!!

Answer (score 0):

As Lulian pointed, downgrading Pillow from 8.3.0 to 8.2.0 solved the issue. Woot woot!!