# TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given (Image classification Keras)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, python-imaging-library

How to troubleshoot this? I've tried setting `dtype=None` in the `image.img_to_array method`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.preprocessing import image

image_size = (180, 180)
batch_size = 32


model = keras.models.load_model('best_model.h5')

img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(
    "GarnetCreek_7-15-2019.jpeg", target_size=image_size
)

img_array = image.img_to_array(img)
img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)  # Create batch axis

predictions = model.predict(img_array)
score = predictions[0]
```

This raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
img_array = image.img_to_array(img, dtype=None)
return image.img_to_array(img, data_format=data_format, **kwargs)
x = np.asarray(img, dtype=dtype)
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Has anyone seen this before? Many thanks!

Comment: What is the type and shape of `img`? Please tell me the version of PIL. `import PIL` then `PIL.__version__`. And try to replace  `from keras.preprocessing import image` by `from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image`

Comment: Image shape is (686, 1140, 3).  PIL version is 8.3.0. I did try to replace the import as suggested but the issue persisted. Thank you!

Comment: Downgrade pillow from 8.3.0 to 8.2 sometimes works. Try it. Downgrade PIL to 8.2.0.

Comment: Wow that worked! Can't thank you enough

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error sometimes is due to a bug in `Pillow 8.3.0` as it is [here](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/5571). (You may not use `import PIL` directly in your code, however some libraries such as [`tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/load_img) use `PIL` internally)

So, downgrading from `PIL 8.3.0` to `8.2.0` may work.

Check `PIL` version:

```
import PIL
print(PIL.__version__)
```

If it is 8.3.0, then you may downgrade to 8.2.0:

```
!pip install pillow==8.2.0
```

Comment: I've tried to downgrade,but without effect. The platform tf2.5,py3.7