# __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given on model.fit in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a small training that runs into the above mentioned error:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import os.path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import seaborn as sns
from time import perf_counter
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, accuracy_score

...
print(train_images)
print(val_images)

m = get_model(tf.keras.applications.VGG16)
print(m)

# Fit the model
history = m.fit(train_images, validation_data=val_images, epochs=1, verbose=0)
...
```

Outputs:

```
<tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.DataFrameIterator object at 0x000001F18B205A90>
<tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.DataFrameIterator object at 0x000001F18B205B20>
<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.functional.Functional object at 0x0000021F1D40E520>
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:/Projects/MTT-Models/main.py", line 205, in <module>
    history = m.fit(train_images, validation_data=val_images, epochs=1, verbose=0)
...
...
TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68239032/2423278

Comment: Edited the Code, I don't have PIL

Comment: wait, does it not need to import PIL to cause this?

Comment: Just because you aren't using it directly doesn't mean a library you're using isn't using it.

Comment: I actually found the other answer before, but thought "I have no PIL". But actually downgrading it solved the issue.