# I am only passing one arguement but it is showing two were given

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, pytorch, ocr, fastapi

My code-:
I have tried to resolve the error but unable to get as the libraries are predefined and iam just calling the function of it.
It was running file earlier but due to some update in torch and torchvision might also be causing it.

```
import easyocr 
import numpy as np
import cv2
   
def read_img(file):
    '''
    Function used to read content of image using Easyocr and return
    the content as text.
    '''

    reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])   #getting English language model
    
    new = cv2.imread(file)            #for loading the image to new from file
    
    results = reader.readtext(np.array(new)) #extracted text by ocr is stored in results
    
    text='' 
    for result in results:            #loop to concatenate all the text to single string
        text += result[1] + ' '
    return text
```

Error which I am facing after running it :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py", line 369, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 59, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 199, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 112, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 181, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 82, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 580, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 241, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 52, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 214, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 151, in run_endpoint_function
    return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\starlette\concurrency.py", line 40, in run_in_threadpool
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, func, *args)
  File "C:\Users\vg_15\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 52, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "G:\restate\Api\.\main.py", line 21, in extract_text
    text = prediction.read_img(temp_file)
  File "G:\restate\Api\.\prediction.py", line 15, in read_img
    results = reader.readtext(np.array(new).astype('float32')) #extracted text by ocr is stored in results
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\easyocr\easyocr.py", line 383, in readtext
    result = self.recognize(img_cv_grey, horizontal_list, free_list,\
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\easyocr\easyocr.py", line 319, in recognize
    result0 = get_text(self.character, imgH, int(max_width), self.recognizer, self.converter, image_list,\
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\easyocr\recognition.py", line 206, in get_text
    result1 = recognizer_predict(recognizer, converter, test_loader,batch_max_length,\
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\easyocr\recognition.py", line 104, in recognizer_predict
    for image_tensors in test_loader:
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 521, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 561, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 47, in fetch
    return self.collate_fn(data)
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\easyocr\recognition.py", line 94, in __call__
    resized_images.append(transform(resized_image))
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\easyocr\recognition.py", line 39, in __call__
    img = self.toTensor(img)
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\transforms.py", line 97, in __call__
    return F.to_tensor(pic)
  File "g:\restate\env\lib\site-packages\torchvision\transforms\functional.py", line 129, in to_tensor
    np.array(pic, mode_to_nptype.get(pic.mode, np.uint8), copy=True)
TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I have tried to resolve the error but unable to get as the libraries are predefined and iam just calling the function of it.
It was running file earlier but due to some update in torch and torchvision might also be causing it.

Comment: Downgrade pillow to something like 2.2.0

Comment: Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68239032/2423278

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: \_\_array\_\_() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given (Image classification Keras)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68238057/typeerror-array-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given-image-class)