# Keras model.fit in Azure ML fails

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, azure-machine-learning-service, model-fitting

I am trying to train a simple test model in Azure ML with few images. I am pushing the training code from my local PC to Azure cloud. It finds the images in the cloud(screen shot below) with Image generator data flow.
[image: validated image]

Model creation also works fine, I can print the summary of the model. But when I am doing model.fit, getting this expected error. But when I am running same code in my local PC, I am not getting any error.

Any lead would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
model.fit(train_generator,validation_data=valid_generator,epochs=1,steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_ad50fdad40ee16a2c46e9c45c93908c0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_ad50fdad40ee16a2c46e9c45c93908c0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1063, in fit
    steps_per_execution=self._steps_per_execution)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_ad50fdad40ee16a2c46e9c45c93908c0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 1117, in __init__
    model=model)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_ad50fdad40ee16a2c46e9c45c93908c0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 916, in __init__
    **kwargs)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_ad50fdad40ee16a2c46e9c45c93908c0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 786, in __init__
    peek, x = self._peek_and_restore(x)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_ad50fdad40ee16a2c46e9c45c93908c0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 920, in _peek_and_restore
    return x[0], x
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_ad50fdad40ee16a2c46e9c45c93908c0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 65, in __getitem__
    return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_ad50fdad40ee16a2c46e9c45c93908c0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py", line 231, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
    x = img_to_array(img, data_format=self.data_format)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_ad50fdad40ee16a2c46e9c45c93908c0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py", line 309, in img_to_array
    x = np.asarray(img, dtype=dtype)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_ad50fdad40ee16a2c46e9c45c93908c0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 83, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Update: the issue got resolved by downgrading the PIL, found the solution from Kaveh's answer in this post:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68238057/typeerror-array-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given-image-class) . I am not deleting this question as someone might be looking for similar issues.

Regards,

Comment: Hi Kaveh, thank you for quick response, I have not check the pillow version in my PC and Azure cloud, will check if that is the reason..

Comment: Hi Kaveh,thanks a lot... yes the PIL version was giving issue, after I downgraded PIL, the error is gone

Comment: Why not give an answer and accept it?