# Problem with creating Lambda layer in keras API model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to execute this code,

```
lyr_in = Input(shape=(400, 400, 3))

# Block 1
lyr = Conv2D(filters=4, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(lyr_in)
lyr = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(lyr)

# Block 2
lyr = Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(lyr)
lyr = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(lyr)

# Block 3
lyr = Conv2D(filters=8, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(lyr)

# Block 4
lyr = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(lyr)

# Block 5
lyr = Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(lyr)
lyr = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(lyr)

# Block 6
lyr = Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu')(lyr)
lyr = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(lyr)


def custom_layer(tensor):
    y = np.zeros((64,400, 400))
    for i in range(0, 25):
         for j in range(0, 25):
              r = 16 * I
              h = 0
              for m in range(0, 16):
                    c = 16 * j
                    for n in range(0, 16):
                          y[:,r,c] = tensor[:,i,j,h]
                          c = c + 1
                          h = h + 1
                          r = r + 1
       return y


  lyr_out = Lambda(custom_layer, name="lambda_layer", output_shape=(400,400))(lyr)
  #lyr_out = Reshape((400, 400))(lambda_layer)

  M1 = Model(lyr_in, lyr_out)
  print(M1.summary())
```

I'm a beginner in Keras and TensorFlow, I want to rearrange the pixel of images in Keras model by a custom layer by lambda layer but i interface this bellow error;

```
TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

how can i fix it friends? thank you very very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: \_\_array\_\_() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given (Image classification Keras)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68238057/typeerror-array-takes-1-positional-argument-but-2-were-given-image-class)

Comment: @Kaveh no unfortunately sir, could you please help me countryman? thank you very much

Comment: This error is because of this line `y[:,r,c] = tensor[:,i,j,h]`. Left side is a list, and the right side  is a tensor. You should use something like `tf.slice`  and `tf.stack` or `tf.concat` to do such operation. However, I recommend to explain what do you want to do in your custom layer, then people may suggest a good way to do so.