# how to solve the problem of img_to_array throwing an array error?

Tags: python, arrays, image, image-processing, keras

when I apply the code on my images;

```
img = load_img('/home/idu/Desktop/COV19D/train/non-covid/ct_scan_0/0.jpg')
x = img_to_array(img)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-c9f48e3c1d97>", line 1, in <module>
    x = img_to_array(img)  # this is a Numpy array with shape (3, 150, 150)

  File "/home/idu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py", line 225, in img_to_array
    return image.img_to_array(img, data_format=data_format, **kwargs)

  File "/home/idu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py", line 309, in img_to_array
    x = np.asarray(img, dtype=dtype)

  File "/home/idu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 83, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I am working with .jpg medical images in an image classification task. I want to build an image generator and flow images from directory later. How can I fix this error?
Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68239032/2423278

Comment: @Kaveh Thank you for the link. Downgrading my pillow version helped solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. If it helped, please don't forget to upvote that answer.