# Convolutional Neural Network with Umap

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset of images with dimensions of (224,224). I want to use a convolutional neural network with `Umap` for dimensionality reduction. Below is the code:

```
input_x = Input((224,224,1))
x = Conv2D(64,3,activation='relu')(input_x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(2, padding='same')(x)   
x = Conv2D(128,3,activation='relu')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(2)(x)    
x = Flatten()(x)   
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)  
x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)

x_umap = umap.UMAP(n_components=10, n_neighbors=15, random_state=42).fit(x)

x = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x_umap)

model = Model(inputs = input_x, outputs = x)
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-387ceb07bc4a> in <module>()
     14 x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
     15 
---> 16 x_umap = umap.UMAP(n_components=10, n_neighbors=15, random_state=42).fit(x)
     17 
     18 x = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x_umap)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68239032/2423278

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: @Kaveh, the error is not related to Pillow.

Comment: @camille, my question, how I can rectify the error.